# Bash split string with delimiter ", " and keep spaces in string

Tags: bash

I have a variable in a bash script that I want to split into an array, with ", " as the delimiter.
This is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
food="cookies, ice cream, candy, candy cane"
IFS=", "
read -ra array <<< "$food"
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$element"
done
```

I have seen [this](http://variable=%22cookies,%20ice%20cream,%20candy,%20candy%20cane%22) post, but as Dennis said, bash will use both "," *and* " " separately.
So then when I run it, "ice" and "cream" are on separate lines, and so are "candy" and "cane" because bash is also treating " " as a delimiter (at least I think that's the reason).

```
cookies
ice
cream
candy
candy
cane
```

How do I split the string so that the spaces in "ice cream" and "candy cane" are left there?
I don't think it matters, but I am on OS X. I used `#!/bin/sh`, but I tried `#!/bin/bash` and got the same result; they should be the same...should they?

Comment: Change `IFS=","` and then `echo "${element# *}"`...

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` vs `#!/bin/bash` *might* matter, depending on exactly what bash features you use in the script (and what OS you're on). Short summary: use `#!/bin/bash`; that way you don't have to worry about what's a basic shell feature vs. a bash extension, 'cause they'll just all work.

Comment: okay, but will the script work on less operating systems if I use `#!/bin/bash`? For example, Ubuntu uses dash, so will some features not work?

Comment: @l'L'l that worked great, can you post that as an answer and explain how that works?

Comment: @user9923191 With `#!/bin/bash` It should work fine on Ubuntu, since that does come with bash installed. With `#!/bin/sh` it would *fail* on Ubuntu, since that's dash, which doesn't support arrays. You're using an array, so you *need* bash, and the shebang should ask for it specifically.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I'll use `#!/bin/bash` from now on, but which operating systems or linux distros don't have bash preinstalled?

Comment: @user9923191 BusyBox, for one -- it just has `ash`. If you want your script to run without bash, you *must* remove all bashisms (like arrays and `<<<`). See [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/865874/bin-sh-vs-bin-bash-for-maximum-portability) for more info & options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your original script a couple of changes should make it work. Remove the space in `IFS=", "` (making it `IFS=","`) then use Shell Parameter Expansion to omit leading spaces.

**Bash Shell Parameter Expansion** (substring removal):

```
${element# }
        |||
        |||_pattern (the space)
        ||_use shortest matching pattern
        |_variable
```

In short this removes one space at the beginning of the string.

> <sub>If the pattern matches the beginning of the expanded value of
>   parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of
>   parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘`#`’ case) or the
>   longest matching pattern (the ‘`##`’ case) deleted.</sub>

If you had multiple spaces to remove then you would want to use a more complex matching method that uses regex perhaps:

```
food="cookies,   ice cream, candy,  candy cane"
IFS=","
re='^( *).*'
read -ra array <<< "$food"
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    [[ $element =~ $re ]] && echo "${element#${BASH_REMATCH[1]}}"
done
```

Before you would have:

```
cookies
 ice cream
 candy
 candy cane
```

And with shell parameter expansion matching the shortest path you get:

```
cookies
ice cream
candy
candy cane
```

If you need to add the variable to a new array then [anubhava's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) solution should work fine for that. You can use either type of parameter expansion (substring removal or his search and replace) method to achieve the same end result.

↳ [GNU | Bash Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)
↳ [Bash Hackers Wiki | Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#parameter_expansion)

Comment: Thanks so much! But, I used `element="${element# *}"; echo "$element"` to make it easier to use.

Comment: `${element# *}` will only remove one space from the beginning of the string, because `#` removes the *shortest* possible match. Also, this uses glob patterns, not regular expressions, so the pattern "` *`" matches a single space followed by *anything* (not zero or more spaces, as it would if interpreted as a regular expression). I'd recommend using just `"${element# }"` (which will also only remove a single space) to avoid confusion.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Yes, you are definitely right; I've updated the answer to show an example using multiple spaces. I believe `${BASH_REMATCH[n]}` is likely the only way to use regex with parameter substitution/expansion, although I'm not completely certain.

Answer (score 4):

You can do a bit of processing in input to replace all `", "` with `","` before reading it into array:

```
food="cookies, ice cream, candy, candy cane"
IFS=, read -ra array <<< "${food//, /,}"
declare -p array
```

```
declare -a array='([0]="cookies" [1]="ice cream" [2]="candy" [3]="candy cane")'
```